# How to access scope from compiler function directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, compiler-directives

I have a directive building html based on an array sent as attribute. I can't access it from the compiler function of the directive. It works inside the link function, but I need in inside the compile, otherwise new template doesn't get compiled.

Code is like this:

```
<multirangeslider values="ranges" variances="['Master', 'master A', 'master B']"></multirangeslider>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module("vtApp.directives").
directive('multirangeslider', function ($parse, $timeout, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            values: "=",
            options: "=",
            variances: "&" 
        },
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            var htmlText, variances, values;
            variances = eval(attrs.variances);

            values = scope.ranges //scope is undefined
            values = eval (attrs.variances) //returns string "ranges"
            values = ???  ///what should I put here?

            htmlText = '<div></div>';
            element.replaceWith(htmlText);
            return function (scope, element, attrs){

            }
        }
    }
});
```

Thank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not have access to the scope until the LinkingFunction which is returned by your compile function. The compile function creates the html template. The scope is then *combined* with the template during the LinkingFunction.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but I would use the standard template or templateUrl object on the linking function as opposed to diving down into the compile function. Somethig like this:

```
angular.module("vtApp.directives").
  directive('multirangeslider', function ($parse, $timeout, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: "<div ng-repeat='val in values'>{{val}}</div>", //Your template code
      scope: {
        values: "=",
        options: "=",
        variances: "&" 
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.values = eval(attrs.variances)
      }
    }
  });
```

You can find more info here about how directives are constructed:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives